# Memory (de)allocation in R loops (without dataframes or growing objects)

Tags: r, memory, garbage-collection, profiling

Consider a simple function that takes a set of probabilities `p` and computes `p*(1-p)`, assiging it to `pq`.

If I call it once, profiling the time & memory allocation

```
p <- runif(1e8)
profvis::profvis({for(i in 1:1) {pq <- p*(1-p)}})
```

[image]
I see that it takes some time and memory, and requires some garbage collection. Ok, fine.

But, if I call it twice

```
profvis::profvis({for(i in 1:2) {pq <- p*(1-p)}})
```

[image]
it requires about twice as much memory and time, and the `<GC>` starts to dominate the time. I think this is happening because memory is allocated to `pq` in the first iteration, de-allocated at the end of the iteration, then re-allocated in the second iteration. In my application this is a problem because I need to call this kind of function repeatedly (obviously with a different `p` each time).

I may be thinking about memory (de)allocation in the wrong way. But, is it possible to simply reuse the memory occupied by `pq`, rather than de-allocate then re-allocate the necessary memory in each iteration?

Comment: *"twice as much memory"* and *"`<GC>` starts to dominate the time"* make sense to me, since one can never really rely on _when_ the collection will occur, but large transactions like this tend to encourage its use more frequently. Note that the first assignment to `pq` is not garbage collected when you reassign back into `pq`, so on the second assignment, the 1e8-long vector is orphaned temporarily until `gc` is able to do its job and look for the orphaned object. From my perspective (not on R-dev), this seems likely to be "normal" with R's copy-on-write semantics.

Comment: @r2evans-GONAVYBEATARMY, would it make any sense to allocate 2 to pq, ie vector length =2, or would that have no impact on orphaning in a 1:1000 context?

Comment: _perhaps_ (really uncertain here): `pq <- 2; gc(); pq <- p*(1-p)` or just `rm(pq); gc(); pq <- p*(1-p)`

Comment: @zachary, could you profviz those suggestions and report?, i think allocating 2 just cuts gc in half and only perhaps.

Comment: I tried both the suggestions from @r2evans in a 2-iteration loop. According to the profiler, less time is spent on GC, but the memory allocation and running time remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

Allocate `pq` beforehand and in the loop use `pq[]` instead. It will reassign in place and GC is avoided.

```
p <- runif(1e8)
pq <- numeric(length(p))
profvis::profvis({for(i in 1:2) {pq[] <- p*(1-p)}})
```

[image]

---

## Note

The `profvis` output of the first code, looping just once is

```
p <- runif(1e8)
profvis::profvis({for(i in 1:1) {pq <- p*(1-p)}})
```

[image]

Comment: My profviz shows <GC> as top line, and appears that `pq[ ] <-` is both more memory intensive and takes longer, as against `pq <- ` for(i in 1:2).

Comment: @Chris What is your version of R? Mine is R 4.2.2.

Comment: "R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)" on very old sse4 chipset. `pq[ ]` -1144M2288  6330 T, `pq` -763M763 2850T

Comment: is there something in `news` on 4.2.2 about [ ] <- that suggests upgrade required to derive the benefit? But, this is probably x:y, as your point was [ ] dispenses with <GC> altogether. Though it is still curious that your profviz doesn't show <GC> whereas mine shows in both.

Comment: @Chris I am surprised too that `<GC>` shows in yours. I don't have an explanation for it.

Comment: packageVersion('profvis')
[1] ‘0.3.7’

Comment: @Chris Same package version here. And `pq[]` 0M1525 130T, `pq` -763M763 1870T.

Comment: I've got to get a new chip set.

Comment: I'm seeing the same as Chris (using 4.2.1 and an M1 Max): GC appears, and the [] method requires both more memory and time.

Comment: but in different places, which I don't know how to  interpret, but  pq[ ]<GC> 0:4 sec  and pq <GC>  ~1.1 :1,75 sec, about where you'd expect it, and happens once.